# pop up close not working got too much recursion jquery error

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

in my view I have a button,button1 ,when click that button I opened a popup, inside that popup I have another button,button2 ,when that button click I need to close the first popup and open another popup.
Here is my code :

```
//showing the popup form when usr clicked the show time
$(document).on('click', '.ticket', function () {
    $('#Popup1').dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        width: 900,
        height: 600,
        resizable: false,
        title: 'Popup 1',
        modal: true,
        open: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).load('@Url.Action("GetSeatSelectionPopup", "BuyTickets")');
        },
        close: function () {
        console.log("test");
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    });
})


//show prepayment form when button "Proceed to checkout" from seat layout pop up clicks
$(document).on('click', '#proceedToCheckOut', function () {
$("#Popup1").dialog("close"); //close popup1
$('#Popup2').dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    width: 900,
    height: 600,
    resizable: false,
    title: 'popup 2',
    modal: true,
    open: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).load('@Url.Action("LoadPrePaymentPopup", "BuyTickets")');
    },
    close: function () {
        $(this).dialog("close");
    }
});
```

})

my problem is that when I click the button1 the popup1 is closed without opening the popup2.
When I inspect using firebug console I got the following error :

too much recursion
ret = computed[ name ];

and console.log("test") on the popup1 close function is executed 350 times .
I get the feeling my approach is wrong
does anyone know of some way to do this? .Would appreciate any help offered. Let me know if you need any other information to help answer this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are closing the dialog in the [close event](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-close) handler of the same dialog, this leads to recursion.

> **close( event, ui )Type: dialogclose**
>
> Triggered when the dialog is closed.

Remove the `$(this).dialog("close");` line from the `close` handler and everything will work as expected.

Comment: that solved my issue .But actually whats going on under the hood ,close event